# Windows Datacenter Server Licensing

Tags: windows, licensing, datacenter, windows-server-2019

my boss purchased a Windows 2019 Data center license. The issue is that a colleague installed it incorrectly, where he installed 2016 Standard on the Host and then tried to use license for the VM's.

This meant that we could only install the license on (I think) 3 of the VM's. So since then, I have taken over this issue and figured that the host needs to be 2019 Datacenter as well as the VM's installed on it.

So I removed the key from the VM's which were already using the key and tried to install it onto the Host (which I reinstalled with 2019 Datacenter), however, it is not accepting the key, it says it has already been used?

Is there a correct method to get this sorted?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx

Comment: I'm not too sure we have a VLSC account, I've just been given the license key they bought and been told the situation. I'm a software dev by trade, so this isn't second nature to me

Comment: Another weird issue is that the link to "Activate by phone" doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by reinstalling the OS. I was then able to activate by phone which got everything working.

The VM's I put on there also need to go through telephone activation, but they all work in the end.